# Open VMX file in VMWare

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I have `Ubuntu-12.4` installed on `VMWare` and I want to edit `.vmx` file to enable `KVM Virtualization`

I have seen a tutorial how to edit but can't find where the `.vmx` file is?

Answer (score 1):

The `.vmx` file is typically located in the directory where you created the virtual machine.

In Linux, run the `vmware-cmd -l` command to list the full path to all registered `.vmx` files.

In Windows XP and Server 2003, the default location for the file is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\your_user_name\My Documents\Virtual Machines\virtual_machine_name.vmx
```

In Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008, the default location for the file is:

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\My Documents\Virtual Machines\virtual_machine_name.vmx
```

[Source](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1714)

Comment: I have hosted Ubuntu in Windows 8 but I dont see any .vmx file in My Documents\Virtual Machines\

Comment: I'd use then the windows 8 search tools: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/search-file-explorer, just type `vmx` as a search pattern